# How can I pass display exposed filter in views-view-unformatted.html.twig?

Tags: views

I would like to display an exposed filter inside views-view-unformatted.html.twig rather than views-view.html.twig due to specific UI design?

Comment: I've provided an answer, but more of an explanation of your use case and where you got stuck would be really helpful.

Comment: Thanks, @Beau! Used Twig Tweak, displayed it using drupal_block, and solved my problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [Views Exposed Filter Blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_exposed_filter_blocks).

- Use the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module and embed the exposed filter block in your template with code like this: `{{ drupal_block('views_exposed_filter_block:my_view_id-my_views_block_id', wrapper=false) }}`.
- You can also just place the exposed filter block in any region.